# How to save the first page of each worksheet as a PDF in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a save pdf button that will save all pages on Sheet1 and Sheet2. Now the problem is I cannot get the VBA code to only save the first page of each worksheet and not save page 1, 2 and 3 of each worksheet.

I have created a save as PDF button that will save Sheet1 and Sheet2 but it prints all pages on each of the worksheets. All I want is page one saved for each of the worksheets.

```
Private Sub PrintAllInvoices()

    Dim FolderPath As String

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\PDFs"

    MkDir FolderPath

        Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & "\Sales", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=1

    MsgBox "All PDF's have been successfully exported."

End Sub
```

I expect it so when the PDF saves it will save Sheet1(Page 1) and Sheet2(Page 1). I only want the first page to be saved of each worksheet.

Comment: Is your goal to save multiple PDF files or just one holding all first pages of the sheets array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, replacing `dir` with your own file path. As long as you have write access to that path you should see a 1-page pdf for each sheet in it after running the macro. Once that works for you, modify as needed.

```
Option Explicit
Sub pdfSavePage()
    Dim sh as worksheet
    Const dir = "C:\Users\Tony\Documents"
    ChDir dir
    For each sh in ThisWorkbook.worksheets
       sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        dir & "\" & sh.Name & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=1, _
       OpenAfterPublish:=False
    next sh
End Sub
```

If you want all those pdf's combined into a single document, this is easily done in the Mac OS using the `Preview` program by simply dragging them into the sidebar area of the first document. No doubt there are other programs that do the same thing in your OS.